# Big-O of my solution to finding common item in two arrays?

Tags: go, big-o

I have a question: my solution to the problem of finding common item in two Arrays was this one:

```
func commonItem2(list1 []string, list2 []string) bool {
    list1 = append(list1, list2...)
    sort.Strings(list1)
    for i := 0; i < len(list1)-1; i++ {
        if list1[i] == list1[i+1] {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
} //O(n)
```

Would that really be O(n)?

Since I'm appending one array to the other and that is as far as I know O(n), don't know the O of the `sort.Strings` function in Go though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorting is not free. You don't need to know the exact complexity of `sort.Strings`, sorting in general is `nLog(n)`

Comment: Your solution doesn't work as described; it will return `true` if one list has any duplicate entries, even if the two lists have no common entries.

Comment: Hey thanks for the fast response, As i was reading your answer it was so obvious,  but without your hint i wouldnt even have noticed.So thanks a lot for that

Answer (score 2):

Time complexity of the sort.Strings function in Golang is O(n*log(n)), in which n is the length of the array.

As today, [internally](https://godoc.org/sort#Sort), sort function makes one call to data.Len to determine n, and O(n*log(n)) calls to data.Less and data.Swap. It uses quick sort for slices with > 12 elements, and uses shell sort for slices with <= 12 elements.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I was doing a bit of Google searching and came to the same conclusion.Learned a lot today.